# Foundation 6 create custom Callout with Sass

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

I wrote this `scss` code to create a custom backround color for my Callout. But how do I change also the `$callout-font-color`? What is the correct way styling my own custom callout with `scss`?

```
.callout.cta {
   @include callout(rgba( $primary-color, .85 ));
}
```